# Need to annotate Django querySet based on which Q object was found

Tags: django, union, django-queryset, annotate, django-q

So I have a query with a few Q objects that are OR-ed together (to achieve a UNION), and I want to annotate each result with which Q object was a match. This is so when I go to display my query results, I can highlight which search term(s) were hits on each result.

Here's the code that produces the resulting querySet:

```
Gene.objects.filter(Q(EC__EC='3.2.1.4')|Q(Protein_Family__name__in=famList)|Q(Pfam__Pfam__in=pfams),Protein_length__gte=100, Distance_From_Contig_Upstream__gte=10, Distance_From_Contig_Downstream__gte=10).distinct()
```

I think I can add this annotated column using the .extra option:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#extra

If I can't do this, I will probably do three separate queries, then annotate the results, then OR the querysets together... I think this is probably pretty wasteful, and seems clumsy.

Comment: You can't OR querysets together. Once they are executed, they are just iterators over the result set. If you need to OR conditions, that's what Q objects are for.

Comment: @saverio actually, you can: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/tests/modeltests/or_lookups/tests.py#L27, however you're right that Q objects should generally be used.

Answer (score 0):

If you annotate with `extra`, the final `distinct` won't work. If you have one record (in the JOINed table) matching the condition on `EC` and another matching the condition on `Protein.Family.name`, then it either gives you one of the matching records (so it will add only the corresponding flag) or it gives you all matching record (duplicating the results in the result set).