# Django istartswith and contains in same query?

Tags: django, postgresql

I need to build a simple username search. I want to have it ordered by usernames that start with the query and then after usernames that contain the string.

if I have a list of usernames like this

- john
- matt
- atom
- atyler
- mrmat

I want it to order like so:

- atom
- atyler
- matt
- mrmat

How would I achieve this in a single query? Right now I have

```
users = User.objects.filter(Q(name__istartswith='at') | Q(name__icontains='at'))
```

But this returns:

- matt
- mrmat
- atyler
- atom

Comment: I don't think you could order by that. Only one ordering could be applied to queryset. You need a list to concatenate 2 querysets to preserve the ordering.

Comment: Is there a way to add a constant value to the results from istartwith and icontains? Where the constant would be the same for all istartswith and a different constant to contains and sort by that at the end?

Comment: This is essentially what I am looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021097/need-to-annotate-django-queryset-based-on-which-q-object-was-found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Z(Func):                                                       
    function = 'ilike'
    template = "%(expressions)s %(function)s 'in%%%%'"


for u in User.objects.filter(username__icontains('in'))\
                     .annotate(q=Z(F('username')))\
                     .order_by('-q', 'username'): 
    print u.username, u.q
```

`ilike` is a postgres extension, for mysql you'll have to either sacrifice case insensitivity or write the corresponding workaround for that.

Answer (score 0):

The "old" way:

```
User.objects.filter(username__icontains='at')\
            .extra(select={'q': "username ilike 'at%%%%'"}, 
                   order_by=['-q', 'username'])
```

This code block filters the queryset and orders it as required by OP.

Also the note about `ilike` from the second answer applies here.

Comment: code blocks on their own aren't very useful, you should at least try to explain how or why this solves the op's issue

Comment: @Saysee If you don't understand a code block that simple an explanation will hardly make it any cleaner for you.